# scansion of a iambic trimeter

Tags: greek, poetry

I'm stuck with the [scansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scansion) of the second of the following lines I read in [Euripides' Bacchae](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Eur.%20Ba.%20435&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0091) :

> 441 κἀγὼ δι᾽ αἰδοῦς εἶπον : Ὦ ξέν᾽, οὐχ ἑκὼν
>
> 442 ἄγω σε Πενθέως δ᾽ ὅς μ᾽ ἔπεμψ᾽ ἐπιστολαῖς.
>
> (translation : [Michael A. Valerie](http://euripidesofathens.blogspot.fr/)) : And I said in gratitude: "This is not done of my own will,
> Stranger, but by order of Pentheus, who sent me."

My best guess :

```
    u -  u  -| u-     -     u -  | u -  u -
442 ἄγω σε Πενθέως δ᾽ ὅς μ᾽ ἔπεμψ᾽ ἐπιστολαῖς.

     ... with a caesura after Πενθέως.
```

The line being a [iambic trimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iambic_trimeter), I clearly see the first and last *metron* : ἄγω σε Πεν ... ἐπιστολαῖς. But what about the second one ? I can't see how to reduce θέως δ᾽ ὅς μ᾽ ἔπεμψ to something like **u - u -** . Everything happens as if -θέως was read as a short syllable before a [caesura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iambic_trimeter#Caesura_and_Bridge). Is it a [synaeresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaeresis) due to the personal name Πενθέως ? See by example Wikipedia's article about the resolutions in iambic trimeters :

> "In tragedy, resolution is fairly uncommon, and substitution occurs almost exclusively to accommodate personal names that otherwise could not fit the meter." as stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iambic_trimeter#Resolution_and_Substitution).

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Πενθέως the second syllable (-θέως) is scanned as a single long syllable. You can call it contraction or synaeresis.

Comment: I forgot the following rule : at the beginning of a *metron*, the first syllable is an *anceps*.